# Finding a number in a string lua

Tags: string, lua, numbers, add-on, world-of-warcraft

A simple question.

When a roll has been done it shows as:

"Need Roll - 150 for [SomeItem] by [SomePerson] + role bonus"

I wish for some way to isolate the number 150.
However there is no such thing as a split in lua (as far as I know) so what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If this is for WoW, check out this [strsplit](http://www.wowwiki.com/API_strsplit) function there.

Otherwise, you can do it with [`string.find` or `string.match` and patterns](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html). It could be as simple as doing a `string.match` for `%d+` to find the first number in the string, as follows:

```
number = string.match(
    "Need Roll - 150 for [SomeItem] by [SomePerson] + role bonus",
    "%d+"
)
```

Comment: If you use string.match instead of string.find you won't need to discard the first two results. Parents around ´%d+´ are not needed in any case. You might have to call `tonumber` in the result: `number = tonumber(string.match(theString, "%d+"))`

Answer (score 5):

`string.match (`*stringvar*`, "%d+")`